# Numerically solve for maximum root

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

I am looking for an efficient algorithm that can numerically solve a piecewise function for its maximum zero root. The piecewise function will normally take the form of the plots below where by below the maximum zero root it evaluates to zero and above the maximum root it evaluates to a negative. The function above the maximum root will always have a negative first derivative (downwards sloping) but could have a positive or negative second derivative as illustrated by the plots below.

I need to make sure that the maximum zero root is found and not a sub optimal root below the maximum one.

Ideally the algorithm would have faster convergence than the bisection method, and similar convergence to newton raphson but with better robustness in finding the maximum root.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you post me please the given function?

Comment: the function is only numerically known from another complex numerical computation and has no algebraic form. The function and its derivatives can only be numerically evaluated.

Comment: Image links appear to be broken. To include images in your post, please use the "image" button in the editor. This will upload them to SE Imgur account, where they are certain to be preserved.

Comment: Do you know how many roots the function should have?  Is it safe to say that finding all the roots and then taking the max is unreasonable?

Comment: You actually end up with an interval of possible solutions. Really need to search for the maximum one first as function evaluations are bit expensive. Ideally want to converge on the maximum solution in a minimum number of steps.

Comment: Is it also expensive to get information about the derivatives of the curve at a given point?

Comment: Yes the derivatives will be expensive too as they will also need to be numerically approximated using a finite difference scheme or something similar which again boils down to function evaluations.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it might end up being that you'd get the best performance from something simple like the regula falsi method, since higher order methods might require more function calls on average.  Hard to say.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I have tried but I don't think the regula falsi method is guaranteed to iterate to the max solution. I think [Brent's method](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/RootFinding/Brent.cs) could be good but again I think the standard implementation is not guaranteed to converge to the max root. I guess my question really becomes how to modify Brent's method so it always finds the max root.